# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not calling after two or three execution

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

In app , i am trying to implement push notification , supports iOS 7 in xcode 7.3 .

after couple of running , now the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called , this is a very strange issue , the device that im running has iOS 9.3.2

here is my functions in appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // self.registerForPushNotificationSystem(application)

//        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
//        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    print("Device Token:", tokenString)
    WebClient.sharedInstace.resgisterNotification(tokenString)
}
```

what might be the issue  this was perfectly working fine yesterday

Comment: It seems that this is an issue on Apple's side. There's another thread (which I can't find right now) stating, that the APNS-Sandbox isn't working. Thus, your delegate methods never get called.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. in my case its not calling one 1st execution too

Comment: Facing the same issue here as well.

Comment: Seems its an issue from app side , still not recovered